# can i upload new movies on youtube with out copy right issue

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I Wanna upload New released Movies On My YouTube Channel So I Had done it but my video was blocked due to copyright issue.

According To Me "**I Had Connected Google Ad Sence With My Channel. That's Why I Think My Video Was Blocked**".Is It Is True?
Can Some Body help Me In my Problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has a complex copyright tracking  system called `ContentID`. It is an automated system that matches your content against a database of copyrighted material. If your video is flagged by the system, you will receive a notice and an opportunity to dispute the flag but your content may be monetized or blocked if you do not win that appeal.

There was a property used for the [status](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) object contains information about the video's uploading, processing, and privacy statuses:

> **status.rejectionReason**    *string*
>
> This value explains why YouTube rejected an uploaded video. This
>   property is only present if the `uploadStatus` property indicates that
>   the upload was rejected.
>
> Valid values for this property are:
>
> - claim
> - copyright
> - duplicate
> - inappropriate
> - legal
> - length
> - termsOfUse
> - trademark
> - uploaderAccountClosed
> - uploaderAccountSuspended

Here is the [Developer Policies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies) using Youtube API.